# Check to see records exist in foxpro database before inserting using parameterised queries

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I have created a program that pulls data from an excel spreadsheet and pushes it to a foxpro database. However I have encountered an issue with duplicate client records appearing.

This is due to one client being associated with multiple other records.

I need to know how to check the database to see if a particular record exists before writing, however I'm drawing a complete blank.

My code (for this particular class) as it stands reads like the below:

```
namespace PropertyImport
{
public class Landlord
{
    public void Import()
    {
        int IDCOUNT = 0;
        using (var exportConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString: Settings.ImportFrom))
        using (var importConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString: Settings.ImportTo))


        using (OleDbCommand exportCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT 
[clcodel salute],
[clcodel fname],
[clcodel sname]
from [export_test$]"
, exportConnection))
        using (OleDbCommand importCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO CLIENT 
        (CLCODE,CLCODEDESC,CLCLASS,
        FNAME,MNAME,SNAME
        )
        VALUES 
        (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                    importConnection))
        {
            OleDbDataReader exportReader;
            //

            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("CLCODE", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("CLCODEDESC", "");
            //importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("CLCLASS", "");
            //importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("NEGOTIATOR", "");
            //importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("TITLE", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("FNAME", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("MNAME", "");
            importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("SNAME", "");

            // Open connections to excel sheet and foxpro database
            exportConnection.Open();
            importConnection.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Visual Foxpro connection open");
            Console.WriteLine("Writing to table");
            Console.WriteLine("...");

            int nLoopCount = 0;
            string space = " ";

            // Initiate the reader to excel
            exportReader = exportCommand.ExecuteReader();
            // Start reading
            while (exportReader != null && exportReader.Read())
            {

                //Set parameter values whilst reading from excel
                string LandTitle = exportReader.IsDBNull(0)
                    ? string.Empty
                    : Convert.ToString(exportReader.GetValue(0)).Trim();
                string LandFname = exportReader.IsDBNull(1)
                    ? string.Empty
                    : Convert.ToString(exportReader.GetValue(1)).Trim();
                string LandSname = exportReader.IsDBNull(2)
                    ? string.Empty
                    : Convert.ToString(exportReader.GetValue(2));
                string CLCODE = string.Concat(LandFname, space, LandSname, " (P)").Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("Working on record {0}, {1}", IDCOUNT, CLCODE);


                importCommand.Parameters["CLCODE"].Value = string.Concat(LandFname, space, LandSname, " (P)").Trim();
                importCommand.Parameters["CLCODEDESC"].Value = string.Concat(LandTitle, space, LandFname, space, LandSname).Trim();
                importCommand.Parameters["TITLE"].Value = LandTitle.Trim();
                importCommand.Parameters["FNAME"].Value = LandFname.Trim();
                importCommand.Parameters["SNAME"].Value = LandSname.Trim();

                try
                {
                    importCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Write("Error Writing to database");
                    Console.Write(e);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                // We must close and re-open the connection after a certain number of records or the OLEDB FoxPro SQL will eventually fail
                if (nLoopCount % 100 == 0)
                {
                    importConnection.Close();
                    importConnection.Open();
                }

            }

            // done
            exportConnection.Close();
            importConnection.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Landlord Import Complete!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            if (Settings.ImportPropertyPause) Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

}
```

}

I want to do something like:

```
if (CLCODE exists)
{
Do not not create record
}
else
{
create record
}
```

Comment: Just do a SELECT on that item - if you get a result back, it exists, if you don't, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there a *single* field value you can check in the target table to see if the record already exists there?  If so, do a "Select * from Table where field = 'blah' " and see if it finds the record.  If it takes *multiple* field values to create the uniqueness that is required to check for an existing record, then just include all the field names and their values and check to see if a record already exists for that: "Select * from Table where field1 = 'blah1' and field2 = 'blah2' "

Comment: cheers, I think i'm onto something now, will post the answer if I solve it

Comment: You don't even need a SELECT. Just add a `WHERE` clause to your `INSERT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joshua,
You are making it unnecessarily complex. On a multiuser environment you would have problems with a "check and insert if not exists" logic. If you think that is not a problem, you could do an ExecuteScalar() to check the count of rows with that clcode. If 0 then it doesn't exist.

If you would do this way, then prefer using Linq. With Linq it would simply be an:

```
bool exists = vfpdb.Clients.Any(c=>c.ClCode == "codetocheck");
```

to see if it exists or not.

Anyway, there is a much simpler way, well it is a trick really but one that works. Assuming you have client.dbf under "d:\backyard\temp" and "d:\temp\myclients.xlsx" file (just for demo purposes that is what I chose):

```
void Main()
{
    string vfpInsert = @"Insert Into client 
    (CLCODE,CLCODEDESC,CLCLASS,FNAME,MNAME,SNAME) 
    SELECT CLCODE,CLCODEDESC,CLCLASS,FNAME,MNAME,SNAME 
     from (Iif(Xmltocursor(?,'xlData') > 0, 'xlData','')) xl 
     where Not Exists
      (Select * From client c2 Where c2.CLCODE == xl.CLCODE)";

    var xml = GetExcelData();

    using (OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection(@"provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source="+@"d:\backyard\temp"))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(vfpInsert,con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("xldata", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = xml;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}

private string GetExcelData()
{
    string dataSource = @"D:\temp\myclients.xlsx";
    DataTable t = new DataTable("Clients");

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
      string.Format("Data Source={0};", dataSource) +
      "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\""))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [clients$]", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        t.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();
    }
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var xmlwriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(ms))
    {
        t.WriteXml(xmlwriter, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        xmlwriter.Flush();
        xmlwriter.Close();
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            return streamreader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is an explanation what the code does:

- Get the data from excel as a DataTable and convert to an XML string.
- Pass XML as a parameter to VFP insert command.
- Insert command, expands the XML to a cursor (almost always in-memory table), and then selects those do not exist already (using ClCode) and inserts them into clients table in one go.